# String of a list into a list

Tags: python

I'd like to find the *quickest way* to change a string of a list with a different types inside, into a list.

For example:

```
string = '[[Date1,Date2,Number1,Number2],[28Dec2018,29Dec2018,1.24,5]]'
```

into

```
list = [['Date1', 'Date2', 'Number1', 'Number2'], ['28Dec2018', '29Dec2018', 1.24, 5]]
```

I know that the module `ast` provides function that could help, but it only works when:

```
string = '[["Date1","Date2","Number1","Number2"],["28Dec2018","29Dec2018",1.24,5]]'
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have YAML installed. Try `yaml.safe_load('[[Date1,Date2,Number1,Number2],[28Dec2018,29Dec2018,1.24,5]]')`

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera And if not, OP _should_ install `yaml`. This is definitely the best answer, or it would be, if it _were_ an answer and not a comment. *wink*

Comment: It is indeed the very best answer so far !

Comment: @J.dlb you may mark the answer that helped you understand and solve your problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = '[[Date1,Date2,Number1,Number2],[28Dec2018,29Dec2018,1.24,5]]'
print(string.strip("[]").split(","))
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Date1', 'Date2', 'Number1', 'Number2'], ['28Dec2018', '29Dec2018', '1.24', '5']
```

EDIT:

```
string = '[[Date1,Date2,Number1,Number2],[28Dec2018,29Dec2018,1.24,5]]'


st = string.strip("[]").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",")
listA = []
listB = []

c = 0
for s in st:
    c = c + 1
    if c <= 4:
        if s.isdigit():
          listA.append(int(s))
        elif re.match("^\d+?\.\d+?$", s):
            listA.append(float(s))
        else:
            listA.append(s)
    else:
        if s.isdigit():
            listB.append(int(s))
        elif re.match("^\d+?\.\d+?$", s):
            listB.append(float(s))
        else:
            listB.append(s)

print([listA, listB])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['Date1', 'Date2', 'Number1', 'Number2'], ['28Dec2018', '29Dec2018', 1.24, 5]]
```

OR

If you don't want to convert the `int` and `float` then its even shorter:

```
for s in st:
    c = c + 1
    if c <= 4:
        listA.append(s)
    else:
        listB.append(s)    
print([listA, listB])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['Date1', 'Date2', 'Number1', 'Number2'], ['28Dec2018', '29Dec2018', '1.24', '5']]
```

OR

As suggested by @Bhathiya Perera in the comments, a one liner killer using [yaml](https://wiki.python.org/moin/YAML):

```
import yaml
print(yaml.safe_load(string))
```

Comment: I think he needs to convert it into as nested list that he can access.

Comment: Actually, the output I get is a bit different, with elements like `'Number2]'`

Comment: Ahh, fixing in a moment!

Comment: The types of `1.24` and `5` need to be converted to their expected type (double and int) presumably too.

Comment: @tobias_k fixed.

Comment: I don't recommend the `yaml.load` use the `yaml.safe_load` instead. From https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation 
Warning: It is not safe to call yaml.load with any data received from an untrusted source! yaml.load is as powerful as pickle.load and so may call any Python function. Check the yaml.safe_load function though.

Comment: Typo `save_load` -> `safe_load`

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera  can't believe that! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to detect everything that does not seem to be a number. Then, `re.sub` all those non-numbers with themselves in quotes, i.e. `r'"\1"'

```
>>> string = '[[Date1,Date2,Number1,Number2],[28Dec2018,29Dec2018,1.24,5]]'    
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=[,\[])(\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*)(?=[,\]])", string)
['Date1', 'Date2', 'Number1', 'Number2', '28Dec2018', '29Dec2018']
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=[,\[])(\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*)(?=[,\]])", r'"\1"', string)
'[["Date1","Date2","Number1","Number2"],["28Dec2018","29Dec2018",1.24,5]]'
```

This is a bit ugly, so let's break that down a bit:

- `(?<=[,\[])`: preceeded by `,` or `[`
- `(\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*)`: letters or digits, actually a letter, and more letters or digits
- `(?=[,\]])`: followed by `,` or `]`

Now, your string is valid JSON<sup>1)</sup> and can be parsed as such with the `json` module:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(_)
[['Date1', 'Date2', 'Number1', 'Number2'], ['28Dec2018', '29Dec2018', 1.24, 5]]
```

This works for the examples given in your question. For other strings, the "letters or digits"-part of the regex would have to be revamped considerably. Alternatively, you might just wrap *everything* in quotes...

```
>>> re.sub(r"([^,\[\]]+)", r'"\1"', string)
"[['Date1','Date2','Number1','Number2'],['28Dec2018','29Dec2018','1.24','5']]"
>>> lst = json.loads(_)
```

... and then recursively cast to `int` or `float` whereever possible in a postprocessing step.

```
def try_to_cast(lst):
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            try_to_cast(x)
        else:
            try:
                lst[i] = float(x)
                lst[i] = int(x)
            except ValueError:
                pass

>>> try_to_cast(lst)
>>> print(lst)
[['Date1', 'Date2', 'Number1', 'Number2'], ['28Dec2018', '29Dec2018', 1.24, 5]]
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> As pointed out [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400200/string-of-a-list-into-a-list/54400552#comment95612958_54400200), your string is *already* valid YAML and thus can just be parsed with the `yaml` module without any pre- or postprocessing.

Comment: What about types _ and % ? it does not seems to work when '1.5 %' or 'ACT_365' are in the list.

Comment: @J.dlb Yes, what about them? They were not in your initial example. Those will make the regular expression considerably more complex, and might allow for false positives (what type should "1.5 %" have, anyway? string or double? and if double, should it be 1.5 or 0.015?). Certainly, you can extend the regex to allow for more cases and keep the rest of the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner utilizing `split`, `strip` and list comprehension;

```
string = '[[Date1,Date2,Number1,Number2],[28Dec2018,29Dec2018,1.24,5]]'
splitter = [x.split(',') for x in string.strip('[]').split('],[')]
print(splitter)

>>>[['Date1', 'Date2', 'Number1', 'Number2'], ['28Dec2018', '29Dec2018', '1.24', '5']]
```

Although as mentioned it doesn't capture the float/int, they return as strings.